# Branding of Search Site in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a project to brand our company's Search Site. I have branded the company's site by creating a custom master page and custom css. I have also branded the landing page using css and js files. I have used Share Point designer to do these tasks.

But I am at a complete lose as to how to start the Search Site. In SharePoint 2013 designer what to do. I cannot even get it to connect to Search Site. I have searched on the web, and there is a lot of info on branding sites and pages, but much on Search Site.

Where do I start? 
How do I add css files?

Much obliged.

Comment: There should be a masterpage for the search center. what is the URL of the search site? is it the same site collection as the primary site?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The search center is a Basic Search Center, and it is a site collection. This site doesn't have the settings icon, so that I could go to the settings. I think that is because I don't have developer privileges on this site collection yet.